# jQuery ui tabs add Gesture for mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, responsive-design, jquery-ui-tabs

i am using [jquery ui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)  to display the content.

there are **bxslider** in the tabs content.

as my site is **responsive** i want to add **gesture** to **jquery ui tabs**.

is it possible to add gesture in jquery ui tabs.?

is there any example to add it? if it's not possible to add gesture to jquery ui tabs then what could be the ideal solution for it?

any help would be greatly appreciated.